# change all new line separators to crlf from cr or crlf on bytes

Tags: java, byte, arrays, newline

I need to change all new line separators to \r\n. In byte table there are some \r and some \r\n

`byte[] data = (byte[]) transformedToByteObject;`

data contains that bytes but i don't know how to handle that change, i need to work on bytes and bytes only , cannot convert to String

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you need to appreciate that a newline character is only a newline character relative to a particular character encoding.  Luckily for you, nearly every character encoding uses an identical ASCII set at the bottom end, and \n and \r are part of that.

There are a number of ways to approach this problem, with varying degrees of efficiency vs complexity.  To take a low efficiency but low complexity approach:

Iterate over the `transformedToByteObject` array, and if a character is not `(byte) '\r'` then copy it to your destination array.

If it is `'\r'` then you also copy it to your destination array, but check if the next character is a `'\n'`. If its not, insert one into the destination array.

Some pointers: your destination array will be at most 2x your input array (worst case, your input array is just full of `'\r'`).  Thus, you can initialise your destination using `transformedToByteObject.length * 2`.  Keep a counter of the actual number of bytes written, and once you know the transformed length, copy those bytes into another byte array of the precise size using `System.arrayCopy()`

One such implementation might look like this:

```
final byte[] original = ...;
final byte[] transformed = new byte[original.length * 2];
int len = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < original.length; i++) // for each original byte ...
{
  transformed[len] = original[i];         // copy the byte
  len++;                                  // track the number of transformed bytes written

  if (original[i] == (byte) '\r')         // if this is a \r ...
  {
    if (i + 1 < original.length &&        // ... and there is a character that follows ...
        original[i+1] != (byte) '\n')     // ... and that character is not a \n ...
    {
      transformed[len] = (byte) '\n';     // ... insert a \n
      len++;                              // ... being sure to track the number of bytes written
    }
  }
}

final byte[] result = new byte[len];              // prepare an exact sized array
System.arrayCopy(transformed, 0, result, 0, len); // and copy the transformed bytes into it
```

Comment: Oops - my code has a bug where if the last character is a `'\r'`, we won't change it to `'\r\n'`. I'll leave it as an exercise to the reader ... ;-)